# What languages can a Professor Orb have?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, languages, intelligent-magic-items

Is a *professor orb* restricted in any way regarding the language choices it can have? For instance, can a *professor orb* know Modron or Vegypygmy as languages?

Additionally, is it possible to possess and use multiple *professor orbs* with the same character?

Comment: Are you a player or the DM?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Your two questions seem entirely separate, and not dependent on one another at all; you should probably edit one of them out and ask it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The DM decides which languages an orb knows.

The description of the [*Professor Orb*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/333435-professor-orb) states (*Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*, p. 284):

> The orb speaks, reads, and understands four languages [...]

It gives no guidance concerning which languages or which types of languages are eligible, so the DM determines which languages an orb knows. Additionally, as a *Professor Orb* does not require attunement, there is nothing preventing a character from owning two *Professor Orbs*, except of course, the DM. If the DM wants to give out two orbs, then they can.